# How to get the records inserted today in a particluar table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get the records inserted today  in a particular table, where there is no field to store record-created-on-date in the SQL SERVER table

Comment: You will need a column with timestamp or that sort in order to know that. At least in terms of sql selects. But you said you didn't have that, so...

Comment: i cannot added one field for timestamp because i have already inserted records

Comment: I get that, but I'm simply telling you that it is in fact needed for the select statement. Your database can have some "tracking" enabled that will allow you to see inserted records for the day in some sort of log etc. but accessing this in a select statement is impossible afaik.

Comment: Alter the tables and add an `updatedAt` and `createdAt` columns.  At least you'll be able to solve this problem tomorrow.

Comment: Please give me other solution. I know this method

Comment: There is no other solution unless you implement auditing

Comment: This is one of those thing that you have to plan for before you need it. :( Perhaps now is a good time to alter that table and add some date columns for tracking for future needs.

Comment: Do you have a backup available that was taken after yesterday's inserts, but before today's inserts? If so, you could brute force today's problem by restoring a copy of the backup and comparing the tables. But, as previously noted, this is something you need to plan ahead for.